# How can i link up my Android phone to unity for Testing Games?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i just started learning unity and i am stuck at linking my Android Phone to unity to test run. Is it possible to test games on android phone from unity? i try with emulator but couldn't work it properly Emulator's Screen goes blue, it did show welcome screen of unity.

My device is xperia arc Android 4.0.4 
is their any synchronization software for unity and android?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

You'll need the xperia drivers.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things you can do.

One, as already pointed by Jerdak, is installing your android device **drivers** and the android SDK. There's no better steps to take here than what [already pointed in the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html), and I see no reason to replicate the steps here.

The second thing is using the "magical" [Unity Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.androidremote&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS51bml0eTNkLmFuZHJvaWRyZW1vdGUiXQ..). It's far from ideal for testing games, but it may be useful for some testing and it is a lot faster and simpler to run. You just need to install it on the device, have it on the same wifi as your running Unity Editor and hit play.

Answer (score 0):

Unity remote is replaced by unity remote 4. Kindly proceed it with unity remote 4.Make sure only 1 sdk platform is installed on your system.